# I want to change Hotspot SSID and Password programatically using ReactNative. is it possible?

Tags: react-native

I do using react-native-tathering package to toggle the hotspot and its work.but know the problem is how to customize the SSID and Password.Any ide to do that?.thank you

I try to use

```
    try {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        Method getConfigMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = (WifiConfiguration) getConfigMethod.invoke(wifiManager);
        wifiConfig.SSID = "newName";
        Method setConfigMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApConfiguration", WifiConfiguration.class);
        setConfigMethod.invoke(wifiManager, wifiConfig);
        System.out.println( wifiConfig.SSID);
        return true ;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
        //  System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
    }
```

it is java and i dont know where and how to call it and also i ddint belive it will work cause WifiConfiguration module are depricated for some version of android.